# How to read Excel in pandas keeping a mixed type column without NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the `dataframe`:

As it is in Excel:

```
stockdf

timestamp    dividend_amount   split_coefficient
10-07-2020   0                   NA
11-07-2020   NA                  1
12-07-2020   0                   1
```

When I try to read this into pandas using: `pd.read_excel(file.xlsx, index_col=0)`

I get

```
timestamp    dividend_amount   split_coefficient
10-07-2020   0                   NaN
11-07-2020   NaN                  1
12-07-2020   0                   1
```

I understand the issue here so I tried:

`pd.read_excel(file.xlsx, index_col=0, converters={'dividend_amount': str})`

A bit of reading got me to: This converts the column after loading the data.

I tried:

`pd.read_excel(file.xlsx, index_col=0, dtype={'divident_amount': str)`

Still the same result.

Comment: try `object` instead of `str`...?

Comment: @JonClements just did same result. The `str` in column is showing as `NaN`

Comment: Does `df = pd.read_excel('your_file', keep_default_na=False)` work in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want attempted conversion of NA values, you can specify that when reading, eg:

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_file', keep_default_na=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to drop rows that are are NaN then use below:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file.xlsx, index_col=0).dropna()
```

Comment: Hi Abhay, I don't want to dropna rows. I was trying to filter a dataframe based on some params.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the problem so that I can help. If you don't want to remove the NaN, then do you want to replace it with some values like mean of coulmn or  0?

Comment: Abhay as mentioned in the question I want to load all it as is. i.e. keep the value from file which is 'NA' and 0. The answer from Jon above is the way to go.